# how to run a shell script present on one linux vm, in another linux vm

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, virtual-machine, vmware

I use VMware vsphere client v5.5. I have developed a simple shell script which basically gives info about the system using the command "lscpu".Now suppose I have two vm's ,both the vm's have RHEL 6.5 installed on them. Suppose I have logged into VM 1 and the shell script is present in this VM1, now I want the info about VM2 and I want to run this shell script file in VM2 from VM1 and get back the result on vm1, how can I do it? One idea I found out was using ssh , but I'm not too sure about it, can anyone let me know how can it be done.

Comment: ssh is a good way. Try googling about "execute remote command over ssh". You'll find a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since, it is run only in VMs (and I presume security is not a concern), you can setup a simple TCP server in VM2 which listens for connections and you can have a netcat client in VM1 which will connect to the server, execute the script and fetch the results.

You can easily achieve this with the help of `xinetd`.

You'll need to install xinetd first. If you are running Ubuntu or ubuntu-based distros:

```
sudo apt install xinetd
```

You'll need to configure xinetd to run your script. I highly recommend referring to this particular guide on [setting up xinetd](https://gtux.in/xinetd-and-painless-tcp-servers.html) to configure your server.

You can just use the default configuration as such.

```
service myscript
{
    type            = UNLISTED
    socket_type     = stream
    wait            = no
    user            = username
    group           = groupname
    server          = /path/to/your/script.sh
    log_on_failure  += USERID HOST
    disable         = no
    port            = 1593
}
```

Just edit the `user`, `group`, `server`(path to your shell script) and `port` fields accordingly and you are set to go.

Once the server is started, you can run your script in VM2 by executing the following in VM1,

```
netcat $vm2_ip $port
```

This will execute the script in VM2 and show the results in VM1.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply ssh over the other vm.

`ssh username@hostname`

enter the password or you can provide it in the initial statement

`sshpass -p password ssh username@hostname`

from here you can execute any command on you VM2 as you would in its terminal.

Explore `cat` etc a little and you can do a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact 2 different questions here:

1. how to execute a command remotely?

   You have plenty of other answers that explains that `ssh` is the way to go. I would just add the precision that as you want to run it from a script, you must configure `ssh` with an asymetric key to avoid it to ask for a password. If you need root priviledges on the target VM you should build a special `sudo` configuration to allow the specified user to access `sudo` without password
2. how to make the command accessible on the remote VM?

   As you have been told, you can read the script on the local VM and pass its lines through ssh to the remote one. But if you want to do a lot of remote administration, it can also make sense to setup a shared file system. You can use NFS, AFS, or even share a common host folder. That allows a single management point for admin scripts, still making them plainly accessible from all your VMs.